# How to fade in/out an HTML DIV container using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have an DIV container with an `id="myDiv"` attribute+value. I'd like to fade this in/out smoothly.

Would I have to create some sort of run loop with an timer and then modify the opacity value of the DIV?

Is jQuery perfect for this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery has [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) methods to create the fading effect. You can for example use them like this on your div:

```
$('#myDiv').fadeOut('slow');
```

Or you can also use the [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method and specify the `opacity` option to it to create the fading effect.

Not to forget about the [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) method too :)

Comment: that "slow" argument is weird ;-) can I also specify the speed in seconds?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is perfect.

```
$('#myDiv').fadeOut();
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/